# Output all documents in mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I am using mongoose ODM and have a schema which looks like this:

```
var banSchema = new Schema({
  userid: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  name: String,
  groupid: String,
  reason: String,
  timestamp: Date
});
```

I want to output every single user id from all documents in the collection. I am using this query to obtain the userid objects. However I cannot seem to get the full list automatically. I have to manually enter the object number as seeen below:

```
bot.onText(/\/sync/i, function (msg) {
    var fromId = msg.from.id;
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    if (fromId == config.sudo) {
        console.log('Sudo Confirmed And Authorized!');
        Ban.find({}, function (err, obj) {
            console.log(obj[0].userid);  // Returns A Single ID
            console.log(obj[1].toObject().userid); // Returns a different ID
            bot.sendMessage(chatId, obj[1].toObject().useridid);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Someone Is Trying To Act Like Sudo! *sigh*');
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'You Are Not A Mod!');
    }
});
```

This however does not return a full list of id's as I want. How could I solve this issue?

The code above is for a telegram bot which on a `/sync` command it should return a message with all ids from the collection.

**Telegram bot API Limits**

Due to the API limits, the entire output should be in a single message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = Ban.find({}).select({
            "userid": 1,
            //Add more column fields here
            "_id": 0  //Ensures _id is not displayed
            });
            var arr = [];
            query.exec(function (err, results) {
                   if (err) throw err;
                   results.forEach(function (result) {
                   arr.push(result.userid);
                   // Add more column fields here;
                   });
                   var fixedJoin =arr.join("\n"); 
                         console.log(fixed);
                   bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'List\n\n' + fixedJoin);
            });
```

Comment: Your method produces an output like this: `{ userid: '58258161' }
{ userid: '135207785' }
{ userid: '268339963' }
{ userid: '210152609' }` of multiple messages. (each userid in a new message)

Comment: I want to avoid multiple messages due to API limits.

Comment: can you share the expected output?

Comment: var query = Ban.find({}).select({ "userid": 1, "_id": 0 });
var arr = [];
query.exec(function (err, results) {
if (err) throw err;

results.forEach(function (result) { 
arr.push(result.userid);
});
console.log(arr); 
});

Comment: This solution is correct too and it provides more flexibility of adding more columns from mongoDB!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get all values of a particular field across all docs in the collection is to use [`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct):

```
Ban.distinct('userid', function (err, userids) {
    // userids is an array containing all userid values in the collection.
    // string.join into a single string for the message.
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'USER IDs\n\n' + userids.join('\n'));
});
```

Comment: The easiest solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax

```
        Ban.find({}).
        select('userid').
        exec(function(err, result) {
            //result is array of userid of all document
        });
```

Comment: Your method produces an output like this: { _id: 57ab3880d6ee316826088850, userid: '58258161' },{ _id: 57ab38a8d6ee316826088852, userid: '135207785' },{ _id: 57ab4721f6d9dffc293bf888, userid: '268339963' },{ _id: 57ac41d09401cefc1566ebfe, userid: '210152609' }` of a single message

Comment: I would prefer a cleaner output of only the userid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```js
Ban.find({}, 'userid', function(err, users) {
    users.forEach(function(user) { 
       console.log(user);
       bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'users \n' + user);
    });
})
```

Comment: Your method produces the cleanest output (first version). However it sends multiple messages instead of one. `58258161
135207785
268339963
210152609`

Comment: @KimMtunguyaz, to send all in one time, you can before running `bot.sendMessage`, `join` all user ids or concatenate by yourself ;)